# Parallels Tools breaks SFML

Tags: graphics, parallels

so I created a clean VM of Xubuntu 14.04.2 in Parallels 10.2.1 and I got SFML working properly with sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev. Then I rebooted and made sure it still worked, and after that the only thing I did was install Parallels Tools. Now when I try to run my sfml-app by command line or through Codeblocks I get the error message:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  1 (X_CreateWindow)
  Serial number of failed request:  74
  Current serial number in output stream:  75
```

Anyone know how Parallels Tools could be causing SFML to malfunction or how to fix this? I can't find anything online about compatibility issues between the two.